# ManyToMany on same table

Tags: symfony, many-to-many

I have a project in which I have a OneToMany relationship on the same database.

Currently it is designed like this:

```
/**
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="MyEntity", mappedBy="myCopiedItem")
 */
protected $mySource;

/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="MyEntity", inversedBy="mySource")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="selected_myentity_copy_id", referencedColumnName="id")
 */
protected $myCopiedItem;
```

But now I have to make this relationship ManyToMany. So I did this:

```
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="MyEntity", mappedBy="myCopiedItem")
 */
protected $mySource;

/**
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="MyEntity", inversedBy="mySource")
 * @ORM\JoinTable(name="entity_has_copy")
 */
protected $myCopiedItem;
```

but the "entity_has_copy" table that symfony created has only 1 item (myentity_id) and I want to have 2 fields "myentity_id" & "selected_myentity_copy_id" which are both actualy id's from my "myentity" table...

What do I have to modify in order to have both id's in my generated table?

I'm sure I've missed something, but I cannot figure out WHAT :(

> Note: Entity / table names were renamed for privacy

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Solved this!

I had to add the relationship inside the definition...

So this is the correct definition for the JoinTable part:

```
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="MyEntity", inversedBy="mySource")
 * @ORM\JoinTable(name="entity_has_copy",
 *      joinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="entity_id", referencedColumnName="id")},
 *      inverseJoinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="entity_copy_id", referencedColumnName="id")}
 *      )
 */
protected $myCopiedItem;
```

Hope this will help others that are having same issue...

If you want to read more about how associations between entities are mapped with Doctrine, here's [a good URL](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/2.0.x/reference/association-mapping.html)!